# How to connect ROS with my Parallax microcontroller?

Tags: ros, microcontroller, rosserial, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have almost no experience writing sorts of serial communication protocols. So far, I have been using rosserial but I keep running into an issue where it states [ERROR] [1550568650.647942]: Lost sync with device, restarting...
, and I have searched up this issue but there is no one definite way. I am trying to publish encoder counts but I'm guessing it's just updating way too quickly to ROS, since the arduino mega only has 8KB of dynamic memory. (I will open another question for this, because I still think rosserial is very convenient for me.)

I want to connect my Parallax ActivityBoard WX Microcontroller from my Arlo Robot to publish messages. I looked at this question, https://answers.ros.org/question/10114/how-can-ros-communicate-with-my-microcontroller/,
and it suggests that I write simply push out messages to a serial port, and use an individual ros node in order to convert those messages.

I am simply just trying to use the microcontroller for the odometry of my wheeled robot. What I was originally doing over rosserial was sending out encoder tick values and then subscribing to cmd_vel messages. Is bridging this connection between microprocessor and ROS feasible for someone with limited serial protocol experience, and if so how should I do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316051/how-to-connect-ros-with-my-parallax-microcontroller?/) by [geistmate](https://answers.ros.org/users/39392/geistmate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-02-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cesarhcq](https://answers.ros.org/users/40890/cesarhcq/) on 2019-06-26**:
Well, i have a simple comment for you. I have an Arlo robot and after some research, i choose to replace for Arduino board (Leonardo), but you can use a Arduino Mega also (its better). I suggest for you. Then, you can use rosserial to establish a communication between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try here: https://github.com/chrisl8/ArloBot and here: https://ekpyroticfrood.net/?p=162

Following the blog and the github instructions enabled me to get my Arlo Robot up and running.

---

Originally posted by [TCIII](https://answers.ros.org/users/45480/tciii/) with karma: 26 on 2021-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0